Using a drone GPS navigator in an AGV
I am designing an Automated Guided Vehicle (AGV) and plan to incorporate GPS navigation. As an automotive engineering student, I am not familiar with using the Pixhawk controller, which is typically designed for drones. Can the Pixhawk controller be adapted for an AGV? If so, how can it be implemented effectively? If not, what alternative controllers would be more suitable for this application?

What is the size of the Automated Guided Vehicle and are there any functional safety requirements to meet to avoid damage to people or property?

The safety requirements is that it will stop when it is approaching an obstacle using an ultrasonic sensor at the distance of 150mm. The size of an AGV is 500mm by 450mm
